# Alternative to writing manually in the console

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a program which scans the input written in the console and gives a result out of it. How can I write this string right into my code, so that I don't have to manually write it down in the console every time I try the program? I'm scanning with java.util.Scanner.

Right now I'm running the tester and type in the 4 words into the console. Then the program gives me the result I want. How can I automate the typing part?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class B6A4_Interpreter {
    public static void eingabe(Scanner sc, PrintStream ps) {
        String position ="";
        String zeichen = "";
        String in = "";
        String satz = "";
        String Ergebnis = "";
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 4) {
            position = sc.next();
            zeichen = sc.next();
            in = sc.next();
            satz = sc.next();
            count = 4;
        }
        sc.close();
        if (position.equals("nach") && (satz.length() != 0)) {
            Ergebnis = satz.substring(satz.indexOf(zeichen)+1);
        }
        else if (position.equals("nach") && (satz.length() == 0)) {
            Ergebnis = "Zeichenfolge";
        }
        else if (position.equals("vor") && (satz.length() != 0)) {
            Ergebnis = satz.substring(0,satz.lastIndexOf(zeichen));
        }
        else if (position.equals("vor") && (satz.length() == 0)) {
            Ergebnis = "";
        }
        ps.println(Ergebnis);
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test_B6A4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        B6A4_Interpreter.eingabe(sc, System.out);

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're talking about. Some code for context would go a long way here.

Comment: How about using a String variable? Paste some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tests here. I suggest JUnit5. But if you don't want to do it, you can manually populate scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("FirstItem SecondItem ThirdItem FourthItem");
        B6A4_Interpreter.eingabe(sc, System.out);
}
```

If you want to have values with spaces you can set delimeter for e.g. new line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("First Item\nSecond Item\nThird Item\nFourthItem");
        sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("(\\n)|;"));
        B6A4_Interpreter.eingabe(sc, System.out);
}
```